# PHP find the days until a date

Tags: php, timestamp, calculation, date-math

I have to find the number of days until a date in timestamp format (mysql db)

```
$row['date_exp'] format is '2013-12-16 10:00:00';
$datenow = date("Y-m-d");
$diff = (strtotime($row['date_exp']) - strtotime($datenow))/(86400);
$days = sprintf("%02d", $diff);
```

My problem is that if date now is `2013-12-01 09:59:00` the days are 15 
while datenow is `2013-12-01 10:01:00` the days are 14.

How could I make a difference only of the days without the time?

Comment: Note that not all days have 86400 seconds. A day could also be 82800 or 90000 seconds due to DST changes, or 86401 or 86399 seconds due to leap seconds.

Comment: mmmhhh Can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Using the [`DateTime`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) class:

```
$a = new DateTime('now');
$b = new DateTime('2013-12-16');

$a->diff($b);
```

returns

```
DateInterval Object
(
    [y] => 0
    [m] => 1
    [d] => 24
    [h] => 8
    [i] => 3
    [s] => 23
    [invert] => 0
    [days] => 54  // This is what you're looking for?
)
```

Comment: Thanks. But I don't understand how can I view the days? Catchable fatal error: Object of class DateInterval could not be converted to string

Comment: `... $diff = $a->diff($b); echo $diff->days;`.

Answer (score 2):

Just take the date component out of it.

```
$newDate = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($row['date_exp']));
```

Now this contains only the date component. You can use this to compare.

Answer (score 0):

One-liner:

```
echo (new DateTime('2019-12-17'))->diff(new DateTime())->days;
```

...returns the number of days **since** *or* **until** `Dec 17, 2019`.

Comment: Sure, it's not formatted to take several lines, but that's intentional since the amount of code required just to handle basic date calculations in PHP drives me *nuts.*